# How to turn off spell checking in CSS?

Tags: css

Any attributes or some tweak to ignore the red-colored underline? or it's ignoreable due to browser settings?

[image]

Comment: `spellcheck="false"` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking

Comment: Perhaps a different problem, but should you try to make your search engine account for misspellings? Solutions just as elasticsearch and solr can do this automatically and are really fast.

Answer (score 23):

It's not CSS but HTML: `spellcheck="false"` in your HTML element should do the trick. But I think Safari for example still draws a red line under it.

Answer (score 6):

It's only possible to do this using HTML5. So you can add the spellcheck attribute to HTML element by using jquery.
Try this

```js
$("#textarea").attr("spellcheck", "false");
```

Comment: Its not the better way, but if you want it, then use:

Comment: This is probably something that should be added to the HTML directly, instead of dynamically using JS after the page has already been served to the user.